# R Markdown difference between parameters and variables

Tags: r, r-markdown

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
params:
  constant1: 22
  constant2: 9
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
constant3 <- 32
constant4 <- 99
```
````

In the R Markdown above why would I define a constant as a parameter in my YAML vs a constant in my setup code chunk? Is there any benefit/difference to using either approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of utilizing parameters is that you can pass these values to a  call to the `render()` function.

```
rmarkdown::render("Untitled.Rmd", params = list(
  constant1 = 123,
  constant2 = 113
))
```

This means you can create a looped or vectorized call to `render()` with a matrix of parameters resulting in multiple variants of your document based on the parameters.  One application is to produce customized reports based on user input (e.g. via a Shiny app).

If your use case doesn't include needing to pass a parameter or matrix of parameters to `render()`, then there is not much difference.